# Maintain ordered child of person in value of Map<String,List<Person>>

Tags: java, sorting, inheritance

```
public interface Person {
    String getName();
    Integer getOrder();
    String getId();
}  
public class HeavyPerson implements Person {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "heavyPerson";
    }
    @Override
    public Integer getOrder() {
        return 2;
    }
    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return "Transport";
    }
}

public class LightPerson implements Person {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "lightPerson";
    }
    @Override
    public Integer getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return "Transport";
    }
}

public class PersonEvaluator {

// map containing id and all its implementation
// Here "transport" id have LightPerson and HeavyPerson implementation.
Map<String, Set<Person>> persons = new HashMap<>();

// How to store set which have sorting based on order.
public void addPerson(Person person) {
    if (!persons.containsKey(person.getId())) {
        persons.put(person.getId(), new HashSet<>());
    }
    persons.get(person.getId()).add(person);
}

public void execute() {
    // TODO execute person based on order. For key "Transport" from map the 
    // values should be taken out in order.
    // order 1 should be executed first
    // order 2 should be executed next.
    }
}
```

Here I want to store implementations of person in a map value in ordered manner. Implementation defines order (like some filters which are executed in ordered manner).

One thing I can do is instead of HashSet use TreeSet but in this case all implementation needs to implements sorting (comparator logic) which is an overhead since sorting will always be fixed for all implementaion.

Any suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't quite understand: Do you want to sort your map by its `String` keys, or do you want to sort the `List<Person>` that are the values of your map? Or both?

Comment: Sort by values. For one key there can be multiple person objects so when I ask for that key from the map I should get all objects for that key in an ordered way.

Comment: "_[with] `TreeSet` ... all implemention[s] need to implement sorting_": NOT TRUE.  The  `TreeSet` can be constructed with a `Comparator` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-)), in which case the set members do not have to be `Comparable`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson. True. I can solve this by passing the comparator function to TreeSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your `*Person` classes to implement `Comparable`, you can simply define `Comparator` and pass it to `TreeSet` constructor:

```java
private static final Comparator<Person> personCmp = (p1, p2) -> {
    return Integer.compare(p1.getOrder(), p2.getOrder());
};


public void addPerson(Person person) {
    if (!persons.containsKey(person.getId())) {
        persons.put(person.getId(), new TreeSet<>(personCmp));
    }
    persons.get(person.getId()).add(person);
}
```